# White Unicode PLAY button rendered gray on Android 4 & 5

Tags: android, html, css, unicode

I am trying to understand why the following Unicode arrow head...

```
 &#9654;
```

...renders flat white in Android Webview when the app is run on Android 7 but is rendered beveled gray on Android 4.4 and 5.1.  Picture below shows the difference.
[image: Difference]

This is the code I am using...

```
<span style="background-color:black;border:none;text-align:center;color:white;
padding: 7px 20px 9px 25px;text-decoration:none;
border-radius:10px;display:none;">
&#9654;&emsp;Listen&emsp;</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that using...

```
&#9658;
```

...instead of...

```
&#9654;
```

...solves the problem.